# How can I return JSON via C# and parse it in JavaScript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asmx

I am using a web service that gets data from my active directory and returns an array of objects to my javascript. The problem is the I am the response encapsulated in Object with _type included when I just want to return the value of the object like this

```
([{ value: "one", label: "Foo" }, { value: "two", label: "Bar" }]).
```

But I am receiving this

```
[Object { __type="Service+NameDTO", value: "one", label: "Foo"}, Object { __type="Service+NameDTO", value:     "two", label: "Bar"}]
```

Here is my c#

```
public NameDTO[] GetCompletionList(string prefix)
{
    var nameList = new List<NameDTO>();
    DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher();
    string strPath = search.SearchRoot.Path;
    DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(strPath);
    search.PageSize = 1000;
    search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(displayName=*" + prefix + "*))";
    foreach (SearchResult sResultSet in search.FindAll())
    {
        if (sResultSet.Properties["mail"].Count > 0)
        {
            var dto = new NameDTO()
            {
                label = (string)sResultSet.Properties["displayName"][0],
                value = (string)sResultSet.Properties["mail"][0],
            };
            nameList.Add(dto);
        }
    }
    NameDTO[] myArray = nameList.ToArray();
    return myArray;
}
public class NameDTO
{
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

and my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#tokenfield').tokenfield({
            autocomplete: {
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '<%#ResolveUrl("~/Service1.asmx/GetCompletionList") %>',
                        data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (data) {
                           response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return data      
                           }))
                        },
                        success: function(response) {
                            $.each(response, function(key, val) {
                                alert(val.id);
                            });
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        }
                   });
                },
                search: function () {
                var term = this.value;
                if (term.length < 3) {
                    return false;
                }
                },
                focus: function () {
                // prevent value inserted on focus
                return false;
                },
            },
      });
});
</script>
```

Comment: what server side tech are you using, wcf, asp.net, asp.net mvc, web api?

Comment: @DanielA.White, he uses `asp.net webservice` i think. Please look his ajax url `/Service1.asmx/GetCompletionList`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need some typical JSON builder.

Server-side, you can make dictionaries, arrays, etc and throw everything into a

```
JsonMapper.ToJson(jsonDict)
```

call.

This function in my project indirectly calls JsonSerializer(), the Newtonsoft JSON handler. Very useful for both serializing and deserializing the JSON.

I may be misinterpreting your question, though; a bit vague.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/10/01/tip-trick-building-a-tojson-extension-method-using-net-3-5.aspx is pretty darn relevant here, and very useful.

It came up that you might need this:

```
var jsonString = @Model; //or however you get your string.
var json = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Comment: I have done that and it seems very close but it is passed as a string of the json but I need a return type of array.

Comment: Why do you need a return type of array? What are you returning _TO_?

Comment: My jquery plugin that I am using accepts an array of objects in format ([{ value: "one", label: "Foo" }, { value: "two", label: "Bar" }])

Comment: Ah, I see!
You're just missing a step. The JSON serializer is necesarry, you simply don't know about JSON parsing in JavaScript from a string. I'll update my answer appropriately now.

Comment: Does it need those parentheses?

Comment: No I'm sorry I should have gotten rid of those just [{ value: "one", label: "Foo" }, { value: "two", label: "Bar" }]

Comment: Everything's working now, then? You just needed that JSON.parse()?
FYI - if you have ' or " somewhere in your JSON, it may be invalid. Look around for how to deal with that; just wanted to forewarn!

Comment: I'm actually not sure. The plugin still is not working but the input does seem to be correct now so you did answer my question. Now onto other issues.